# Getting a list of configured HttpHandlers

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

My **Web.Config.xml** file is configured a set of supported extensions to clients' http requests. These requests are handled by the same `HttpHandler`  implementation. I use the extensions to enable functionality in the handler. Below is a copy of the structure.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">          
        <add name="Handler1" path="*.path1" verb="*" type="namespace.class, assembly" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="Handler2" path="*.path2" verb="*" type="namespace.class, assembly" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="Handler3" path="*.path3" verb="*" type="namespace.class, assembly" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
        <add name="Handler4" path="*.path4" verb="*" type="namespace.class, assembly" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>        
</system.webServer>
```

I wish to implement a 5th handler so that clients can make an initial request to get the supported paths (functionality), so that they will not try to make requests that are not supported. I wish to control enabled functionality by adding / removing handlers.

**How can I get a list of the configured handlers run-time in my Handler implementation?**

I wish to use the list to construct my response.

I have looked at `System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlersSection` but when I try to get `system.webServer` section, I get an `System.Configuration.IgnoreSection` object back.

Comment: Take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151434(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @S.Petrosov It seems that the system.webServer element is not supported by the "WebConfigurationManager.GetSection". It returns a System.Configuration.IgnoreSection object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to read the `system.webServer/handlers`, you need to reference the

> Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll

in place of `System.Configuration`.

The dll can be found in the \windows\system32\inetsrv folder when you have enabled the IIS Management Console in Windows features.

[image]

Here is some sample code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of configured handler names
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter">the handler name must contain this value to be included in the list</param>
/// <returns>a list of handler names that matches the filter or all handler names if filter is null</returns>
public static List<string> GetHandlerNames(string filter)
{
    string websiteName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
    Configuration o = srvMgr.GetWebConfiguration(websiteName);
    ConfigurationElementCollection c1 = o.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers").GetCollection();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        return c1.Where(x => x.GetAttribute("name").Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant())).Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("name").ToString()).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return c1.Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("name").ToString()).ToList();
    }
}   


/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of configured handler paths 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="filter">the handler name must contain this value to be included in the list</param>
/// <returns>a list of handler paths that matches the filter or all handler paths if filter is null</returns>
public static List<string> GetHandlerPaths(string filter)
{
    string websiteName = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
    Configuration o = srvMgr.GetWebConfiguration(websiteName);
    ConfigurationElementCollection c1 = o.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers").GetCollection();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        return c1.Where(x => x.GetAttribute("name").Value.ToString().ToLowerInvariant().Contains(filter.ToLowerInvariant())).Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("path").ToString().Replace("*.", "")).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        return c1.Select(x => x.GetAttributeValue("path").ToString()).ToList();
    }
}
```